# android architecture components AndroidViewModel instance couldn't be created. Trying to make a simple Room DB

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components, androidx

Here'e My Class Extending AndroidViewModel where I'm trying to get my Database context through application constructor but when i'm calling this from MainActivity it's throwing me an error saying java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.roomdb33.BookViewModel

```
public class BookViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

 final BookDAO bookDAO;





public BookViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
   BookRoomDB bookDB = BookRoomDB.getDatabse(application);
    bookDAO = bookDB.bookDAO();

}



//For Inserting
void insert(BookEntity book){

    InsertAsyncTask insertAsyncTask = new InsertAsyncTask(bookDAO);

    insertAsyncTask.execute(book);
     static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<BookEntity,Void,Void>{

    final BookDAO bookDAO;

InsertAsyncTask(BookDAO bookDAO) {
    this.bookDAO = bookDAO;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(BookEntity... bookEntities) {
    bookDAO.insert(bookEntities[0]);
    return null;
     }
   }
  }
```

My BookRoomDB has a method getDatabase Which is below

```
static BookRoomDB getDatabse(Context context){
    if (bookRoomDB == null){
        synchronized (BookRoomDB.class){
            if (bookRoomDB == null){
                bookRoomDB = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),BookRoomDB.class,"book_database")
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's how I'm calling in my MainActivity

```
 BookViewModel bookViewModel;
 bookViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BookViewModel.class);
```